# How to keep async, many-to-many relationships up to date using EmberData

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Given the following models:

```
var post = DS.Model.extend({
    tags: DS.hasMany('tag', {async: true, inverse: 'posts'})
});

var tag = DS.Model.extend({
    posts: DS.hasMany('post', {async: true, inverse: 'tags'})
});
```

Adding or removing a tag looks like this:

```
var post = this.get('model');

this.store.createRecord('tag', {}).save().then(function (tag) {
    post.get('tags').then(function (tags) {
        tags.addObject(tag);

        post.save().then(function () {
            tag.get('posts').then(function (posts) {
                posts.addObject(post);

                tag.save().catch(function (res) {
                    // handle errors
                });
            });
        }).catch(function (res) {
            // handle errors
        });
    });
});
```

I feel like there must be a better way of handling the thenables - but I am still trying to wrap my head around promises and how to use them properly.

So, what is the best way to add or remove a tag from a particular post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately updating async hasMany relations is fairly cumbersome. So your solution is *(at least at the current state of ember data)* already quite good. One thing you could optimise though is not having to save the newly created `tag` two times. Since your async relation is sending only the id of the posts anyway you can add your current post immediately when you create the tag like so:

```
post = this.get('model');
this.store.createRecord('tag', {posts: [post]}).save().then(function (tag) {
  post.get('tags').then(function (tags) {
    tags.addObject(tag)
    post.save().catch(function (res) {
      // handle errors
    });
  }
}).catch(function (res) {
  // handle errors
});
```

..and here, without failure callbacks it's easier to read:

```
post = this.get('model');
this.store.createRecord('tag', {posts: [post]}).save().then(function (tag) {
  post.get('tags').then(function (tags) {
    tags.addObject(tag)
    post.save();
  }
});
```